# Google plus share not working with 'gmail' domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, google-plus, google-plus-domains

I am new in laravel 5.2. When I am trying to share a content into google plus, it shares only to an email rather than to 'gmail' as  domain.

For example it will share to `example@domain.com` but **not to** `example@gmail.com`.

**Code in Context**

```
 public function gplusEventShare($value,$new_event){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    $client->setClientSecret('xxxxxxx');
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setScopes(array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write'    
    ));
    $social_id = $value->social_id;
    $accesstoken = $value->social_token;
     //return $client->refreshToken('xxxxxxxx');
    if ($value->refresh_token) {  
        $oauth2token_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
        $clienttoken_post = array("client_id" => 'xxxxxxxx',
            "client_secret" =>'xxxxxxxx',
            "refresh_token" => $value->refresh_token,
            "grant_type" => "refresh_token");

        $curl = curl_init($oauth2token_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $clienttoken_post);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $new_gplus_token = json_decode($json_response);
        $value->social_token=$new_gplus_token->access_token;
        $value->save();
        $accesstoken = $new_gplus_token->access_token; 
    }
    $url='https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/'.$social_id.'/activities';
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization : Bearer '.$accesstoken,
        'Content-Type : application/json'

    );  
    $post_data=array("object"=>array("originalContent"=>'Join us for the event'),"access"=>array("items"=>array(array("type"=>"domain")),"domainRestricted"=>true));
    $data_string=json_encode($post_data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $file_result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Isnt that what you are telling it to do?  ),"access"=>array("items"=>array(array("type"=>"domain")),"domainRestricted"=>true));

Comment: @DaImTo ..I tried with d‌​omainRestricted"=>false. But same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [Google+ Domains API Scopes](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes) docs specifies that that scope only lets you share within the Google Apps domain.

> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write`
>
> Grants permission for the app to create posts or comments on behalf of a user. The Google+ Domains API only allows creation of [restricted posts](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2705802), and only allows comments to be added to restricted posts.

Comment: To add to this: there is no API to make public posts on Google+. **This restriction is intentional**, and is unlikely to ever be lifted.

Comment: G+ sharing is working for all domain other than  gmail, is there any additional permission or settings needed to working on 'gmail' domain too, can you please give a sample code of g+ share?